# Hyperledger explorer docker connection error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I created hyper ledger fabric network configuration and docker is running based on that. After that, I installed .bna file on that network.

I am trying to set up Hyperledger explorer docker images to explore data. I set explorer my folder structure as given as in the instruction.

[image]

my config.json file is like below.

```json
{
    "network-configs": {
        "network-1": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "clients": {
                "client-1": {
                    "tlsEnable": true,
                    "organization": "EngineeringMSP",
                    "channel": "testchannel",
                    "credentialStore": {
                        "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Engineering/credential",
                        "cryptoStore": {
                            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Engineering/crypto"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "channels": {
                "testchannel": {
                    "peers": {
                        "peer0.engineering.test.com": {}
                    },
                    "connection": {
                        "timeout": {
                            "peer": {
                                "endorser": "6000",
                                "eventHub": "6000",
                                "eventReg": "6000"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "organizations": {
                "EngineeringMSP": {
                    "mspid": "EngineeringMSP",
                    "fullpath": false,
                    "adminPrivateKey": {
                        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/engineering.test.com/users/Admin@engineering.test.com/msp/keystore"
                    },
                    "signedCert": {
                        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/engineering.test.com/users/Admin@engineering.test.com/msp/signcerts"
                    }
                },
                "OrdererMSP": {
                    "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
                    "adminPrivateKey": {
                        "path": "/tmp/crypto/ordererOrganizations.test.com/users/Admin.test.com/msp/keystore"
                    }
                }
            },
            "peers": {
                "peer0.engineering.test.com": {
                    "tlsCACerts": {
                        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/engineering.test.com/peers/peer0.engineering.test.com/tls/ca.crt"
                    },
                    "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
                    "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053",
                    "grpcOptions": {
                        "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.engineering.test.com"
                    }
                }
            },
            "orderers": {
                "orderer.example.com": {
                    "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "configtxgenToolPath": "./bin",
    "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

After I am executing command `./deploy_explorer.sh poc <network name>` I am getting error like.

```
postgres://hppoc:password@192.168.10.11:5432/fabricexplorer
/bin/sh: locate: not found
/bin/sh: locate: not found
/bin/sh: locate: not found
error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
at checkState (/opt/explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:838:16)
2018-10-19T05:59:05.103447389Z 
**************************************************************************************
Error : Failed to connect client peer, please check the configuration and peer status
Info : Explorer will continue working with only DB data
**************************************************************************************
2018-10-19T05:59:05.103656561Z 
2018-10-19T05:59:05.114643537Z 
2018-10-19T05:59:05.114721428Z 
Please open web browser to access ：http://localhost:8080/
2018-10-19T05:59:05.114745161Z 
2018-10-19T05:59:05.114749276Z 
pid is 6
2018-10-19T05:59:05.114757612Z 
2018-10-19T05:59:05.114761455Z 
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

I checked my postgers db which is in docker container and it don't have any data in fabricexplorer database tables.

can anyone help me?

Comment: One assumes you followed https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#steps-to-deploy-using-docker and were in the correct directory for your custom install ?

Comment: I see you asked on the #explorer Rocketchat channel - it could be an install bug - see also the threads https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/BE-405?focusedCommentId=47894&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-47894 and https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/hyperledger-explorer?msg=BwG8a27NuB7qQakHS - on that channel - lastly: FYI there's a sample config here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/examples/net1/config.json - not sure whether you're using grpc or grpcs

Answer (score 0):

Change all the urls in your config.json to, example:

```
"orderers": {
            "orderer.example.com": {
                "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
            }
        }
```

Should be

```
"orderers": {
            "orderer.example.com": {
                "url": "grpc://orderer.example.com:7050"
            }
        }
```

Follow up on instructions in blockchain-explorer/examples/net1/README.md

Comment: Please learn [how to format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and use the preview pane to check your post.